# strcat not affecting global string

Tags: c, c-strings, strcat

im trying to add strings of varying length to the end of a string and it's not behaving as I would expect it to. the global string stays empty after the addToString function ends

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * string = "";

void addToString(char * string,char* arg){
  unsigned int new_string_len = strlen(string) + strlen(arg);
  if(strlen(string) == 0){
    string = malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
    strncat(string,arg,strlen(arg) + 1);
    printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(string),string);
  }
  else{
    string = realloc(string,new_string_len);
    strncat(string,arg,new_string_len);
  }
}

int main(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    addToString(string,"boop");
    printf("%s",string);
  }
  printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(string),string);
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: `unsigned int new_string_len = strlen(string) + strlen(arg);` should be `unsigned int new_string_len = strlen(string) + strlen(arg) + 1;` for the NUL-terminator. `strncat(string,arg,strlen(arg) + 1);` should be a `strcpy`. And remember: `strncat` doesn't end the string with a NUL-terminator

Comment: Change declaration to `void addToString(char *& string, const char* arg)`

Comment: so using `strncpy(string + strlen(string),arg,strlen(arg));` instead of  `strncat(string,arg,strlen(arg) + 1);` protects me because it would preserve the null terminator?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have two ways to modify `string` variable that either pass the address of the variable or since it is global variable don't pass it to function as parameter. The following codes show respectively what I mean,

Due to global variable, no need to pass,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

char * string = "";

void addToString(char* arg){
    unsigned int new_string_len = strlen(string) + strlen(arg) + 1;
    if(strlen(string) == 0){
        string = malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
        strncat(string,arg,strlen(arg) + 1);
        printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(string),string);
    }
    else{
        string = realloc(string,new_string_len);
        strncat(string,arg,new_string_len);
    }
}

int main(){
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        addToString("boop");
        printf("%s",string);
    }
    printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(string),string);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Passing its address,

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

//char * string = "";

void addToString(char ** string,char* arg){
    unsigned int new_string_len = strlen(string) + strlen(arg) + 1;
    if(strlen(*string) == 0){
        *string = malloc(strlen(arg) + 1);
        strncat(*string,arg,strlen(arg) + 1);
        printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(*string),*string);
    }
    else{
        *string = realloc(*string,new_string_len);
        strncat(*string,arg,new_string_len);
    }
}

int main(){
    char * string = "";
    for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
        addToString(&string,"boop");
        printf("%s",string);
    }
    printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(string),string);
    free(string);
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`string` being a global variable (more technically a non-static one) allows every function (in every file which get's linked to this) to be able to access it. What this means is, every function, i.e. `addString()` and `main()` in this case, see it implicitly. You don't need to explicitly pass it as a parameter.

Remove the first parameter in `addString` and it'll concatenate just fine.
i.e. your new `addString` method is:

```
char * string = "";

void addToString(char* arg){
     // the same code as before, unmodified.
}

int main(){
  for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++){
    addToString("boop");
    printf("%s",string);
  }
  printf("%lu %s \n",strlen(string),string);
  return 0;
}
```